# Python for loop is passing a number strangely

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to python and web scrapping.

While scraping data from a web page using selenium, I discovered a phenomenon that suddenly broke out of the for loop, but i don't know why

```py
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

i = 0
keyword_address_list = []
while True: 
        try:
            now_list = []
            for j in range(1,51):
                print("%s page %s element" %(i, j))
                path = '${some xpath}' %(j)
                target_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path).text

                # need to scroll down every 10th element.
                if (j % 10 == 0):
                    tartget_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path)
                    tartget_element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
                    time.sleep(1)
                now_list.append(target_text)

                keyword_address_list.extend(now_list)
        # except:
        #     print("exit")
        #     driver.switch_to.default_content()
        #     keyword_address_list.extend(now_list)
        #     break

        finally:
            i += 1      
            keyword_address_list.extend(now_list)
            now_list.clear()
            
            # move to next page
            print("click")
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            driver.switch_to.frame(result_frame)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '{next button xpath}').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            tartget_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '{target to scroll up xpath}')
            tartget_element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

this is my print texts and stack trace

```
{keyword}
0 page 1 element
0 page 2 element
0 page 3 element
0 page 4 element
0 page 5 element
0 page 6 element
0 page 7 element
0 page 8 element
0 page 9 element
0 page 10 element
0 page 11 element
click

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [186], in <cell line: 19>()
     42 print("%s page %s element" %(i, j))
     43 path = '{some xpath}' %(j)
---> 44 target_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path).text
```

I traced this issue by hand, and found that the number that should be passed to 10 was input as 1 in the string format in the for loop.

Comment: It looks like element 11 can't be found. Perhaps it doesn't exist? It may be safer and easier to find all the elements and iterate over them, rather than use a counter and increment by 1 each time. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#find-elements-from-element

Comment: @nofinator 
since the data on this web is dynamically generated whenever you scroll down, I thought to scrape it by class name after scrolling down to the end, but the necessary data was created in the iframe tag, and unfortunately I couldn't find a way to scroll the iframe.

Comment: @nofinator I found another webpage where I could get the same information, and I got the data in a way you told, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You are tring to find that element which is not available on webpage. You have to run loop only till you are getting data.
If you have 10 data on webpage you have to run loop 10 time only. If your page has 10 data and you are run loop till 11 It will give 'NoSuchElementException' because 11th element is not available.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Orloff Yeah! your right!
There was an error for some reason, and I solved it by changing the method to get all elements at once.